# How to create/parse an array list...from a csv list?

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I am confused on how to go about parsing an array list from a .csv file.
The .csv file gives information on a daily basis, in this format:

```
{
       "a" : 1,
       "b" : 3,
       "d" : 10
},
```

The open bracket shows the new day of data, and the closing bracket followed by the comma ends the data (I have no way of changing how the .csv is generated).  There are about 400 days worth of data, and each day has the same list items (a,b, and d).  How would I go about parsing the .csv data into a readable list format in python?  I would post example code, but I have no idea where to even start with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like JSON to me...

Comment: Tyler, it very well could be, I am not sure on how the data is exported.  I am using python to interpret the .csv that is generated in that format.

Comment: Are there commas between the `a` and `b` fields (e. g. is it `{"a" : 1, "b": 3` or `{"a" : 1 "b" : 3` as in your example)?

Comment: Sean, there are commas between the fields.  I have updated the original question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV file is almost certainly JSON. If it is, then Python has a [`json`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html) library you can import and use:

```
import json

with open('/path/to/your/file.csv', 'r') as file
    data = json.load(file)
    # do things with data here
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to import it correctly following your code!  A simple json.dumps(data) allows for the customization of arrays (via numpy) for those interested.

Answer (score 1):

for parsing csv

```
import csv
a = ["1,2,3","4,5,6"]   # or a = "1,2,3\n4,5,6".split('\n')     
x = csv.reader(a)

print(list(x))
>>> [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```